# JavaScript - Convert an Array of Objects with Key-value pair to Array of Arrays with values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var myArray = [
        {
            name: "abc",
            age: 23,
            rank:208
        },
        {
            name: "pqr",
            age: 25,
            rank:178
        },
        {
            name: "xyz",
            age: 21,
            rank:108
        }
   ];
```

I expected result:

```
var newArray = [['abc', 23, 208], ['pqr', 25, 178], ['xyz', 21, 108]];
```

I tried to find solution but don't know what to search on internet. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```js
var myArray = [{
  name: "abc",
  age: 23,
  rank: 208
}, {
  name: "pqr",
  age: 25,
  rank: 178
}, {
  name: "xyz",
  age: 21,
  rank: 108
}];

function convertToArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var arraySection = [];
    var obj = arr[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
      arraySection.push(obj[key]);
    }
    newArray.push(arraySection);
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(convertToArrayOfArrays(myArray));
```

Comment: Awesome. Very simple and clean solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use map, this allows it to be short and concise.

```
var newArray = myArray.map(function (item) {
    return Object.keys(item).map(function (subitem) {
        return item[subitem]
    });
});
```

Or if you happen to be using ES2015 (a newer version of JavaScript):

```
let newArray = myArray.map(item => Object.values(item));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = [];
for (i in myArray){
  var newArray = [];
  for(j in myArray[i]){
    newArray.push(myArray[i][j]);
  }
  result.push(newArray);
}
```